# Low pass shape curve with low cycle count

Tags: c, arm, embedded

[image: The curve I want to achieve in software]

Hi, I want to achieve the above curve in software without using a dsp function. I was hoping to use a fast and low cycle arm function like multiply-accumulate.

Is there any fast way of doing this in C on an embedded arm processor?

Comment: Yes, C is generally pretty fast, and the ARM architecture is supported by a variety of compilers.

Comment: You are showing what looks like a continuous time response.  You won't get something exactly like that in the discrete time domain but you can get close.  You may want to look at [Design IIR Butterworth Filters Using 12 Lines of Code](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1119.php)

Comment: You mean without using "DSP hardware" or "DSP instructions"?  What you are asking is digital-signal processing regardless of how it is implemented, so a "DSP function" is rather a given.

Comment: What is your actual processor and actual speed?  "_Embedded ARM processor_" covers a wide spectrum from 20MHz Cortex-M0 to multi-core 64-bit phone application processors. What is your sample rate? If you are writing this is C it will be up to the compiler whether it uses a Multiply-Accumulate instruction.  A low pass 20dB/Decade (6dB/Octave) can be implemented as a 1 single pole IIR; it depends on what else your processor is doing and your performance requirements, but at audio frequencies at least, such a filter will not trouble the processor much.

Comment: More important perhaps is sample acquisition, processing one sample at each ADC interrupt will be far less efficient and fail at lower sample rates than using DMA acquisition and sampling larger blocks on a single DMA interrupt.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome : To be clear those "12 lines of code" are twelve lines of MATLAB code and are for the _design_ (i.e. determination of the coefficients) not the _implementation_ - which this question is about.  This filter requires far fewer that 12 lines of C to implement.

Comment: The "idealised" curve is defined for a frequency range f to 100000f suggesting a sample rate of 200000f.  What are your "real-world" requirements in terms of bandwidth - because the curve shown probably exceeds those and would be hard to achieve in practice.

Comment: What is your current implementation and how does it not meet your performance requirements?  If you don't have an existing implementation then this is a premature optimisation - if you implement it and it is fast enough, ten it is well... fast enough.  And in that case your question is really one of how to implement the filter, not how to make it "fast".

Comment: Yes. It's totally possible to implement a IIR filter using genera purpose instructions.  In general form, each output sample will be a weighted sum of input samples.  This is pretty much the use-case for multiply-accumulate instructions.  You will also find that the multiplications are by constants, and it may be cheaper to implement these without adds and shifts.

Answer (score 2):

The curve shown is that of the simplest possible first-order filter charactarised by a 3dB cut-off frequency *f<sub>c></sub>* and a 6dB/Octave or 20dB/Decade roll-off. As an analogue filter it could be implemented as a simple passive RC filter thus:

[image]

In the digital domain such a filter would be implemented by:

- *y<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>0</sub> x<sub>n</sub> + b<sub>1</sub> y<sub>n-1</sub>*

Where *y* are input samples and *x* output samples.  Or in code:

```
void lowPassFilter( const tSample* x, tSample* y, size_t sample_count )
{
    static tSample y_1 = 0 ;

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        y[i] = a0 * x[i] + b1 * y_1 ;
        y_1 = y[i];
    }
}
```

The filter is characterised by the coefficients:

- *a<sub>0</sub> = 1 - x*
- *b<sub>1</sub> = x*

where x is a value between 0 and 1 (I'll address the eradication of the implied floating point operations in due course):

- *x = e<sup>-2πf<sub>c</sub></sup>*

Where *f<sub>c</sub>* is the desired -3dB cut-off frequency expressed as a fraction of the sample rate.  So for a sample rate 32Ksps and a cut-off frequency of 1KHz, *f<sub>c</sub>* = 1000/32000 = 0.03125, so:

- *b<sub>1</sub>* = *x* = *e<sup>-2πf<sub>c</sub></sup>* = 0.821725
- *a<sub>0</sub>* = 1 - *x* = 0.178275

Now naïvely plugging those constants into the `lowPassFilter()` will result in generation of floating point code and on an MCU without an FPU that might be prohibitive and even with an FPU might be be sub-optimal.  So in this case we might use a fixed-point representation.  Since all the *real* values are less than one, and the machine is 32bit, a UQ0.16 representation would be appropriate, as intermediate multiplication results will not then overflow a 32 bit machine word.  This does require the sample width to be 16bit or less (or scaled accordingly).  So using fixed-point the code might look like:

```
typedef uint16_t tSample ;

#define b1 53852    // 0.821725 * 65535
#define a0 (1 - b1)

#define FIXED_MUL( x, y ) (((x)*(y))>>16))

void lowPassFilter( const tSample* x, tSample* y, size_t sample_count )
{
    static tSample y_1 = 0 ;

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        y[i] = FIXED_MUL(a0, x[i]) + FIXED_MUL(b1, y_1) ;
        y_1 = y[i];
    }
}
```

Now that is not a significant amount of processing for most ARM processors at 32ksps suggested in this example.  Obviously it depends what other demands are on the processor, but on its own this would not be a significant load, even without applying compiler optimisation.  As with any optimisation, you should implement it, measure it and improve it if necessary.

As a first stab I'd trust the compiler optimiser to generate code that in most cases will meet requirements or at least be as good as you might achieve with handwritten assembler.  Whether or not it would choose to use a multiply-accumulate instruction is out of your hands, but if it didn't the chances are that it is because there s no advantage.

Bare in mind that ARM Cortex-M4 and M7 for example include DSP instructions not supported in M0 or M3 ports.  The compiler may or may not utilise these, but the simplest way to guarantee that without resorting to assembler would be to use the [CMSIS DSP Library](https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/DSP/html/index.html) whether or not that provided greater performance or better fidelity than the above, you would have to test.

Worth noting that the function `lowPassFilter()` retains state staically so can be called iteratively for "blocks" of samples (from ADC DMA transfer for example), so you might have:

```
int dma_buffer_n = 0
for(;;)
{
    waitEvent( DMA_BUFFER_READY ) ;
    lowPassFilter( dma_buffer[dma_buffer_n], output_buffer, DMA_BLOCK_SIZE ) ;
    dma_buffer_n = dma_buffer_n == 0 ? 1 : 0 ; // Flip buffers
}
```

The use of DMA double-buffering is likely to be far more important to performance than the filter function implementation.  I have worked on a DSP application sampling two channels at 48ksps on a 72MHz Cortex-M3 with far more complex DSP requirements than this with each channel having a high pass IIR, an 18 coefficient FIR and a Viterbi decoder, so I really do think that your assumption that this simple filter will not be fast enough is somewhat premature.